# Intercept Excel Open File

Tags: excel, vsto, ms-office, add-in, xll

Is there a way to intercept or override Microsoft excel's File open command by an COM Addin? I want to process the file before Excel tries to open the workbook, so Application_WorkbookOpen is too late.

Ideally it should be triggered when an excel file is double-clicked also.

Comment: Would a native C COM add-in (an XLL) help me?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
Public Sub Auto_Open()

End Sub
```

It works even before `Application_WorkbookOpen`. Not sure if it is fast enough for you though.

Update:

[This might be helpful for you too.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa211920%28v=office.11%29.aspx) Different ways to auto execute macros:

```
AutoExec
AutoNew 
AutoOpen 
AutoClose
AutoExit
```